# Jordan form of an $n \times n$ Jordan block with eigenvalue $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Suppose $J$ is an $n \times n$ Jordan block with eigenvalue $0$, what is the Jordan form of $J^2$?

**My solution:**

I squared the matrix, it follows that the eigenvalues are $0$ again, and $\dim(N(J^2)) = 2$, with eigenvectors $e_{n-1}$, $e_{n}$.

Therefore, the Jordan form of $J^2$ is an $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ block and two $1\times1$ blocks all with eigenvalue zero.

However, there is a hint with the question which says to treat odd and even values of $n$ separately but I fail to see why.

Answer (score 2):

Let me illustrate this with the $n = 6$ case. Here, we have a basis $\{ e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, e_5, e_6 \}$, and the action of $J$ on the basis vectors is given by
$$ Je_1 = e_2, \ \ Je_2 = e_3, \ \ Je_3 = e_4, \ \ Je_4 = e_5, \ \ Je_5 = e_6, \ \ Je_6 = 0. $$
So the action of $J^2$ on this basis is given by

$$ J^2e_1 = e_3, \ \ J^2e_2 = e_4, \ \ J^2e_3 = e_5, \ \ J^2e_4 = e_6, \ \ J^2e_5 = 0, \ \  J^2e_6 = 0.$$

[You absolutely right that the kernel of $J^2$ has dimension two, and is spanned by $e_5$ and $e_6$.]

But here is the really key point. Notice that, under the action of $J^2$, the vector space decomposes into *two invariant subspaces*:

- There is the subspace spanned by $\{ e_1, e_3, e_5 \}$, on which the action of $J^2$ is
  $$ J^2e_1 = e_3, \ \ J^2e_3 = e_5, \ \ J^2e_5 = 0.$$
- Then there is the subspace spanned by $\{ e_2, e_4, e_6 \}$, on which the action of $J^2$ is
  $$ J^2e_2 = e_4, \ \ J^2e_4 = e_6,  \ \ J^2e_6 = 0 .$$

So $J^2$ has *two* Jordan blocks (corresponding to these two subspaces), and for *each* of these two blocks, the Jordan matrix is
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

That was the $n = 6$ case. Can you generalise this approach for $n = 7$? And from there, can you generalise for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Thank you that clears things up I can finish it out from there. More generally when does the "key point" come into play? and do you have any references I could see about that because I've always assumed if you have eigenvectors for an eigenvalue   of multiplicity 'n' it follows that you get an (n - 2) jordan block automatically

Comment: @Scosh_lr I'm afraid I don't think I've ever come across such a theorem. To give you another example, suppose we have a $4\times 4$ matrix $A$,  and  I tell you that $A$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue, and no other eigenvalues, and that the dimension of the eigenspace corresponding to the zero eigenvalue is 2-dimensional. Then there are two possible Jordan forms for $A$: either it has a 3-dimensional block and a 1-dimensional block, or it has two 2-dimensional blocks. The fact that the dimension of the eigenspace is two means that we have two _blocks_.

Comment: why is it not possible to have a 2x2 block and two 1x1 blocks?

Comment: @Scosh_lr Because in that case, the eigenspace would have dimension three. (To spell it out, if $e_1, e_2$ span the $2\times 2$ block, and $e_3$ spans a $1 \times 1 $ block and $e_4$ spans the other $1 \times 1$ block, then $Ae_1 = e_2$, $Ae_2 = 0$, $Ae_3 = 0$ and $Ae_4 = 0$, so $e_2, e_3, e_4$ are all eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$.)

Comment: Oh I see now, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong.  For example, 
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 \cr
           0 & 0 & 1\cr
           0 & 0 & 0\cr}^2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}
    \ \text{has Jordan form}\ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$
(a block of size $2$ and a block of size $1$) but
$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr
            0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr
            0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr
            0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}^2 = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 &  0 & 0 & 1\cr
             0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}\ \text{has Jordan form}\ 
    \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$
(two blocks of size $2$).